# Which of these 1-D representations of the Navier-Stokes equations is correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

The incompressible Navier Stokes equations can be written as

**A.**
$$\frac{\partial (\rho \mathbf{v})}{\partial t} + \nabla \cdot (\rho \mathbf{v} \mathbf{v}) = S$$

or

**B**.
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{v}}{\partial t} + (\mathbf{v} \cdot \nabla) \mathbf{v} = \frac{S}{\rho}$$

where $S$ is some source term. But it seems these not the same in 1-d...?

**A.**
$$\frac{\partial (\rho v)}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial (\rho v^2)}{\partial z}= S$$

$$\frac{\partial (\rho v)}{\partial t} + \rho\frac{\partial v^2}{\partial z} + v^2\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial z}= S$$

Let $\rho = 1$
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial v^2}{\partial z} = S$$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + 2v\frac{\partial v}{\partial z} = S$$

is not the same as

**B.**
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial z} = \frac{S}{\rho}$$

Let $\rho = 1$

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t} + v\frac{\partial v}{\partial z} = S$$

So what am I missing? Which version is correct?

Answer (score 4):

**GENERAL DEVELOPMENT:**

First we establish the equivalence of the two forms for the Navier-Stokes Equations given in the OP.

To do  this, we use straightforward product rule differentiation to show that

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \rho \vec v}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}\vec v+\rho \frac{\partial \vec v }{\partial t} \tag 1
\end{align}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
\nabla\cdot (\rho \vec v \vec v)&=(\rho \vec v \cdot \nabla)\vec v+\nabla \cdot (\rho \vec v)\vec v \tag 2\\\\
&=(\rho \vec v \cdot \nabla)\vec v-\frac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}\vec v \tag 3
\end{align}$$

In going from $(2)$ to $(3)$ we used the continuity relationship

$$\nabla \cdot (\rho \vec v)+\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} =0 \tag 4$$

which is an integral component of the physics of the problem.  Now, using $(1)$ and $(3)$ reveals that

$$\begin{align}
\vec S&=\frac{\partial \rho \vec v}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot (\rho \vec v \vec v)\\\\
&=\rho \frac{\partial \vec v }{\partial t} +(\rho \vec v \cdot \nabla)\vec v\tag 5
\end{align}$$

whereupon dividing $(4)$ by $\rho$ yields

$$ \frac{\vec S}{\rho}=\frac{\partial \vec v }{\partial t} +(\vec v \cdot \nabla)\vec v \tag 6$$

where we have established that the alternative forms are equivalent given $(4)$.

---

**ONE-DIMENSIONAL CASE:**

Note for the one-dimensional case, the reduced forms of $(4)$ and $(5)$ become

$$\frac{\partial \rho v}{\partial z} +\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0 \tag {4'}$$

and

$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac{\partial \rho v}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial (\rho v^2)}{\partial z}\\\\
&=\rho \frac{\partial  v }{\partial t} +\rho  v \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}
\end{align} \tag {5'}$$

If the density $\rho$ is constant, then we have further simplification of $(4')$ and $(5')$.  The continuity equation becomes

$$\frac{\partial  v}{\partial z} =0 \tag {4''}$$

while the Navier-Stokes equation becomes

$$\begin{align}
S&=\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}
\end{align} \tag {5''}$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 3):

They are both correct.  Remember you also have the divergence free condition:
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} = 0 .$$
Note, this makes the 1D incompressible NS equation quite boring.

Comment: What if we have the compressible Navier Stokes equations. Then which one is correct? (I meant compressible in the question)

Comment: I have never seen the compressible NS written using A.

Comment: I have fixed the question!

Comment: Oops, I got it wrong.  The compressible NS is written using A.  Then it is shown that this is the same as B in the incompressible case.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#General_continuum_equations.  So clearly form A is the correct equation.  But edit your question to make it clear you are talking about compressible NS, not incompressible NS.